# Adding new column using string contains python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some help, I want to add a new column from parts of a existing column.
I used str.contains but it gives me this error:
*unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'*

This is my code:

```
df['VVD'] = df[df['hashtags'].str.contains('rutte', 'mark', 'vvd')]
```

I know this is not the correct way of doing this but I'm struggling to find out how I can do this.

Comment: try ``df['hashtags'].str.contains("rutte|mark|vvd")``

Comment: Thankyou! I think this is almost it, but now the new column just contains true or false and I want it to contain the text

Comment: hi @Sophia, kindly add an example dataframe with expected output. Easier to work with visuals and give a more detailed/appropriate solution. Kindly share data, not pics.

Comment: @Sophia did you pass the boolean index back into `df`? `df['VVD'] = df[df['hashtags'].str.contains("rutte|mark|vvd")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a column to a dataframe!

Try this:

```py
cond = df['hashtags'].str.contains('rutte|mark|vvd')
df['VVD'] = df.loc[cond, 'hashtags']
```